# python2.7 decorate function from external module used in another external module

Tags: python-2.7, decorator

I have 3 files `a.pyc`, `b.pyc`, and `c.py`

file `a.pyc`:

```py
def f(x):
    # do something with x and get y
    return y
```

file `b.pyc`:

```py
from a import f

def g(x):
    z = f(x)
    # process z and get w
    return w
```

I can't modify these files but I can `c.py` and code in it will be executed before `b.pyc` question is can I add decorator (and how) in file `c.py` to function `f` and when function `f` will be called in `g` code in decorator will execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# a.py

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self, x):
        xx = x+100
        print xx
        return xx

# b.py

from a import A


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def g(self):
        x = self.a.f(3) + 1000
        print x
        return x

# c.py

from functools import wraps
from a import A


def run_before(module, func_name):
    def decorator(callback):
        func = getattr(module, func_name)

        @wraps(func)
        def run_before_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            callback(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        setattr(module, func_name, run_before_wrapper)
        return callback

    return decorator


def run_after(module, func_name):
    def decorator(callback):
        func = getattr(module, func_name)

        @wraps(func)
        def run_before_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            callback(*args, **kwargs)
            return res

        setattr(module, func_name, run_before_wrapper)
        return callback

    return decorator


@run_before(A, 'f')
def sstart(*args, **kwargs):
    print "start"

@run_after(A, 'f')
def sstop(*args, **kwargs):
    print "sstop"


from b import B

bb = B()

print bb.g()
```

returning

```
start
103
sstop
1103
1103
```